# When opened in smaller-scale browser window, page shows zoomed in

Tags: html, reactjs, css-grid

I am trying to build a registration/login page form with create-react-app. 
So far I developed a web-layout where I used css-grid. I developed it on display with a resolution of 1920 x 1080. When I opened the same page on a smaller resolution screen(1536 x 864), I found out it is kinda zoomed in, so it gets OK again when I zoom out to 80%.
[When opened in 1920 x 1080 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcOyQ.jpg)
[When opened in 1536 x 864 display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwzMO.jpg)

I have tried to change the viewport of index.html inside create-react-app, however it didn't change.

HTML:

```
<div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <div className={classes.headerMessage}><h3>Welcome to the online-bartering system</h3></div>
        <div className={classes.insideWrapper}>
          <div className={classes.wrapperLeft}>
            <form onSubmit={this.signInHandler}>
              <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: "blue", display: "inline" }}>Sign In</h2> <img src={SignIn} />
              <h6 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Already registered ? Then enter username and password below: </h6>
              <div className={classes.wrapperLeft_content}>
                <label>
                  Username <input type="text" name="nameLogin" placeholder="username" onChange={this.handleChange} />

                </label>
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.nameLoginErr}</div>
                <label>
                  Password <input type="password" name="passwordLogin" placeholder="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.passwordLoginErr}</div>
                <button type="submit" id="signIn">Sign in</button>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div className={classes.wrapperRight}>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: "red" }}>Sign Up</h2>
            <h6 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Not registered yet ? Then, please provide your user information below: </h6>

            <div className={classes.wrapperRight_content}>
              <form onSubmit={this.signUpHandler}>
                <label>
                  Username* <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="username" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.state.nameErr}</div>
                <label>
                  Password* <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.passwordErr}</div>
                <label>
                  Repeat Password* <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" placeholder="repeat password" value={this.state.repeatPassword} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.passwordErr}</div>
                <label>
                  E-mail* <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{this.state.emailErr}</div>
                <button type="submit" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
              </form>

            </div>


          </div>
        </div> 
        <div className={classes.advertImages} >


            <div> 
            <img src={ManImage} /> 
            </div>
            <div> 
            <img src={WatchImage} />
            </div>
            <div> 
            <img src={Cars} />
            </div>
            <div> 
            <img src={Smartphones} /> 
            </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div className={classes.footer}>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  min-height: 100%;
}

body{
  background-image: url('../images/background.jpg'); 
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: none;
  scroll-behavior: unset;
  overflow: hidden; 


}


.wrapper{
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); 
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px 600px ; 
  background: none; 
  margin: 80px 150px;  
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-content: start;  
   margin-top: 0 ;


} 



.headerMessage{
  background-color:  rgb(147, 147, 199); 
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  font-size: capitalize; 
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 2rem; 
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: azure;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;

} 
.headerMessage h3{
  color: rgb(4, 17, 5); 
  opacity: 1;  


}

.insideWrapper{
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 5fr; 
    grid-column-gap: 1em;  
    max-height: 240px;
}



.wrapperLeft{ 

  background-color:  #97a1aa; 
  opacity: 0.8; 
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}

.wrapperLeft img{ 
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline; 
  float: right;
}

.wrapperLeft_content{
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapperLeft_content button {
 width: 120px; 
 border-radius: 80px;
}

.wrapperLeft_content button:hover{
  border: 2px white solid; 
}


.wrapperRight{
  background-color:  #ecde1a; 
  opacity: 0.8;
  max-height: 350px;
  text-align: center; 
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;

}

.wrapperRight_content{

  display: inline-block;
} 

.wrapperRight_content button {
  width: 120px; 
  border-radius: 80px; 
  background-color: #b9b797; 
  opacity: 0.9;
 } 
 .wrapperRight_content button:hover{
   border: 2px white solid; 
 }


label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  height: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
} 

.advertImages{
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 5fr 5fr;;
} 
.advertImages img {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: black; 
  color: white; 
  max-height: 25%;
  top:auto;


} 

.footer h5 {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
} 

.footer img {
  width: 0.4in;
  height: 0.4in; 
  position:relative; 
  display: inline; 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I expect that the web-layout would adjust to the screen resolutions, since in create-react-app index.html meta viewport is available.

Comment: Add the complete html, the rendered one better (and better even with fiddle). Most cases in my experiece are because meta viewport is forgot or incorrect, doublecheck it. Other times the problem is the size units... but with the provided info I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your index.html, for it to stay fix on every screen and on every event, trigger like Input focus

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: I already have this meta inside create-react-app project index.html, it doesn't solve it.

Comment: then maybe you can add screenshots of how it looks on both the screens?

Comment: hi, I added the pictures how it looks on different screen resolutions.